# What do you even call the ability of code to auto update and how do you do it?

Tags: loops, clojure, game-development, read-eval-print-loop, auto-update

I'm having a hard time understanding how to even search online for this behavior. I've seen it several times before and know it's something that can be done but don't know if this is a language level feature or what. What do you call the ability for code that you edited to automatically be applied to an executed instance of said code being run.

To use a common version of this that I see: you'll have a game that you're developing open and you'll be running that game in your engine and then edit a value (let's say one representing walking speed) and then simply save that file (maybe compile it? maybe just that line? I don't know how it's done) and then, suddenly, that behavior is updated in the live instance of the program just like that.

It seems so much better then having to recompile a file, or a whole project, and then run it to be able to test it. How do I do this kind of rapid iteration and what is it called? NOTE: the first time I saw this was with Clojure in emacs. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: hot reloading ?

Comment: Yup! That did the trick and hit up all the resources I needed. Hot reloading a.k.a. [hot swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping). This then led me to [interactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_programming) and [interactive computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_computation) and a whole bunch of other stuff. Very useful. Thanks!

Comment: There is also a related term, "late binding", that is used for a property of the language that allows the binding between a name/symbol and a value/object to be delayed to just before its use.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about [the Clojure REPL](https://clojure.org/guides/repl/introduction) and [also here](https://www.braveclojure.com/getting-started/).

"Hot Reloading" is related and is commonly used in UI development in the browser with ClojureScript:

- [Shadow CLJS](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs)
- [Figwheel Main](https://figwheel.org/)

Comment: I'm familiar with REPL in the way it was described. I've used it before and it is awesome, but I was really interested in, what I now know is, hot reloading stuff. Thanks for the info though and confirming.